# Shipping costs or shipment costs?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

*shipping costs* or *shipment costs*?

I want to know the correct form and the difference between them, if there is one.
Thank you!

Comment: To simplify: Merchandise, product, ware, commodities offered for sale etc. is "shipment" and something that serves as a means of transportation of moving goods and materials is shipping.

Answer (score 5):

`Shipping costs` seems to be the favored expression ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shipping%20costs%2C%20shipment%20costs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshipping%20costs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshipment%20costs%3B%2Cc0))

Perhaps because **shipment** has two meanings: ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shipment))

> 1. The action of shipping goods:
> 2. A quantity of goods shipped; a consignment:

So, `shipment costs` could mean the cost of the consignment, which is not the implication here.